# find out when chrome is presenting clientside certificate to the server for authentication

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, client-certificates

I am working on client side certificate authentication. 
in Web client in chrome browser, when I visit the server first time, SSL handshake happens and I can see that browser presented the client certificate because it poped a dialouge saying

> "select a certificate to which you want to authenticate"

but,
I want to know when browser is presenting the certificate again in case of time-out.

It there any developer tool that can be used to find it out?